# Ubuntu21.10 won't read a DVD, not any dvd, just one. The same dvd works fine on my windows laptop

Tags: dvd

I'm currently checking out old DVD's containing familiy pictures, I wasn't having any issue until one of them, after being inserted in my laptop, simply didn't show up in the file manager.
I ran the command `sudo lshw -C disk` , still nothing.
I thought it was damged so i doubled check with another machine running windows vista: there it says the disk is blank but it does say that some space is occupied on it..?
Finally I tried a third laptop running windows xp where i was surprised to see it pop up normally with all my pictures inside.

Does anyone have any clue what might be the cause?

Comment: Is is possible that when it was burned that it was burned using the setting of making it like a USB drive where it doesn't close out the disc until it is full?  Windows had a funny notion like that of giving you 2 options, one for being used on any computer that would close the disc after you added files, the other would keep the disc open.  An open disc cannot be read on anything but the computer it was opened on.

Comment: Possible:  https://superuser.com/questions/827693/check-if-cd-dvd-is-finalized

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know this! I checked and the disk seems to be finlized as it shows 0 free space while containing only 2Gb out of the 4.7 available out of the box so I think I can rule out this option unless i misunderstood something

Comment: Try installing the libdvd-pkg.  `sudo apt install libdvd-pkg` as there might be some navigation for that disc that it may not be recognizing.  Kind of hard to say since I am not sure how that disc was burned.